# Assertion or Runtime Error holds execution in thread instead of code-line

Tags: swift

Whe using a normal "assert()" statement xcode stops where the thread execution takes place.

I tried to play around with adding

```
exection breakpoints
```

But I still can't get xcode to actually stop at the line where the assertion happens.

E.g.

```
    let x:String? = nil
    assert(x != nil )
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to add a general exception breakpoint in the breakpoints pane.

Before adding an exception breakpoint, Xcode stops in the App Delegate as you mentioned, but with this enabled then it will stop on the `assert` statement itself.

[image: Add Exception Breakpoint]

[image: Xcode stopped on an assertion]

Comment: Interesting, I don't recall ever having that fail to work for me. Sorry I can't be of more help!